# Simplest way to Convert to invalid date to a moment object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have store hour information that is given like this

- Sunday 8:00
- Sunday 22:00

Since it is store hour information the year, month, and date do not matter but unfortunately I still need to this information to be a moment object for formatting/ Organisation reasons.

What is the simplest way to convert this invalid date format into a moment object.

I've heard of sugar and it seems perfect but my team will not want to have to install it for just one simple thing, so no libraries unless it is something included in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the input format:

```
moment("Sunday 8:00", "dddd hh:mm");
```

[Reference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: tried this initially used .format to identify the format thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly you already have the Date javascript Object. Then you can just set it using:

```
var day = new Date(2011, 9, 16);
var dayWrapper = moment(day); //or your JS Date object.
```

You can read it at Moment.js doc: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/